# How to read large files using SwiftUI DocumentGroup without making a temporary copy?

Tags: swiftui, documentgroup

I have made a SwiftUI DocumentApp that reads large media files but doesn't need to write them. In my document, I just want to store the file's URL, so that I can load it using e.g. AVAudioFile. I can't work out how to do this without creating a temporary copy of the file, as the author does [here](https://wwdcbysundell.com/2020/creating-document-based-apps-in-swiftui/), because there is [no way to the file URL from the fileWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846193/get-path-for-nsfilewrapper)

I have attempted to create a pipe using the configuration.file.regularFileContents (Data), but so far I had no success reading from that pipe.

```
  init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
    let tempURL = makeTemporaryFileURL()
    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: tempURL.path, contents: configuration.file.regularFileContents, attributes: nil)
    audioFileUrl = tempURL
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get `fileURL` via document configuration, like

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(viewing: MyDocument.self) { fileConfig in
            // here fileConfig has `fileURL` of opened document, so 
            MyViewer(content: fileConfig.document, url: fileConfig.fileURL)
        }
    }
}
```